# Workflow to follow a record via Chatter

Tags: chatter, workflow, administration, follow

Along the lines of this plugin for Salesforce:  http://www.spkeasey.com/chattomate

Anyone know how to write a **Workflow to follow a record in Chatter**?

I want to be able to program specific objects to have them followed by record-creator, not ALL objects.

Example:   Auto-follow Cases and Tasks when created "by me".

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an autolaunched flow to do this. Have the flow create an EntitySubscription record when you conditions are met.  The triggering workflow would manage your criteria and pass the record ID into the flow.

Ultimately Process Builder was/is the solution here.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I like where you're going with this... especially if you're implying you can run a flow "automatically" which I didn't think you could do.   Will look into this ASAP...... thanks!

Comment: If you are OK waiting 2 weeks until the Spring release comes out, then you can use the Process builder to execute an Autolaunched Flow:  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_action_flow.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

Was pretty quick to do this.

You need to create a variable in the Flow. Then in the Process Builder you'll password the ID of the record (Account, Case, etc) to that variable.

In the flow, when you create the EntitySubscription record it will look something like this:

ParentId = {!PassedParentID}

SubscriberID = 00580000008TqH2 (this is your ID, if the auto follow only applies to you)

Hopefully this link works: http://www.screencast.com/t/439V5oZtrtmf

Answer (score 0):

I've got code for this as part of ProcessBuildetBlocks.

Video here: https://youtu.be/D1Me5QFil1w

Code here:
https://github.com/mshanemc/processBuilderBlocks/blob/master/src/classes/PBBChatterFollow.cls